# Programmatically do "Git blame -w" in C#

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp, git-blame

I need to programmatically get the last author of a specific line in the Git history with C#.
I tried using [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) :

```
var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(gitRepositoryPath);
string relativePath = MakeRelativeSimple(filename);
var blameHunks = repo.Blame(relativePath);
// next : find the hunk which overlap the desired line number
```

But this is the equivalent of the command

`git blame <file>`

And in fact I need

`git blame -w <file>` (to ignore whitespace when comparing)

*Libgit2sharp* do not set the `-w` switch and don't provide any parameter/option to set it.
What are my options ? Do you know any other library compatible with the `-w` switch of the `blame` command ?

Comment: Just to clarify you have tried NGit?

Comment: @Jeremy : not at all, I didn't know NGit. I spent so much time on this question that I prefered ask for feedback.

Comment: Cool, this is a really good feature request for the LibGit2Sharp dev team :) If you ask them politely referencing a link to this Q, you might encourage one of the core team or a contributor to add it while this Q has an active bounty attached... Otherwise Evk should get it (+1). Fingers crossed that's enough to persuade because then you wouldn't need to rely on 2 libraries.

Comment: @Jeremy : the feature request is already [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1177) (since Aug 2015).

Comment: The problem with lib2gitSharp is that it is using lib2git, which is "a portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods provided as a re-entrant linkable library with a solid API, allowing you to write native speed custom Git applications in any language which supports C bindings." which doesn't have the whitespace option. It doesn't execute git, so you can add -w, it implements everything. I tried to implement it myself, but C code makes me dizzy. Probably you will have to do with NGIT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I hit similar advanced scenarios where the git lib isn't cutting it, I just shell out using start process to the real git command line.  It's not sexy, but it's mighty effective.

Comment: I though about that before, but I need to do this for about 2000 files in my solution, and feared on performance. I'll try it as a last resort.

Comment: In fact this way is really faster than using libGit2Sharp in my case. With a test repository of 818 files (4570 commits), with a blame on each file: using direct process : average of 181 ms. per blame ; using ligGit2Sharp : average of 1235 ms per blame.

Comment: necro posting because this is still the #1 hit for this question.  It is now 2019 and the blame implementation in libgit2 is still an order of magnitude slower than command line git according to https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3027

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using NGIT library will help. That is direct (automatic) port of java JGIT library. Install via nuget package, then:

```
    static void Main() {
        var git = Git.Init().SetDirectory("C:\\MyGitRepo").Call();            
        string relativePath = "MyFolder/MyFile.cs";            
        var blameHunks = git.Blame().SetFilePath(relativePath).SetTextComparator(RawTextComparator.WS_IGNORE_ALL).Call();
        blameHunks.ComputeAll();
        var firstLineCommit = blameHunks.GetSourceCommit(0);
        // next : find the hunk which overlap the desired line number
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Note SetTextComparator(RawTextComparator.WS_IGNORE_ALL) part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try this the next week.

Comment: No way to make this working. Some commits are nice, and some others are just null. Especially when there are whitespace differences. I don't know if I have a wrong or missing option, or if it's just due to the outdated  sources of ngit (compared to jgit). I give up, I'm going back to basics (robrich solution).

Comment: Nevertheless I give you the bounty because the answer is theoretically correct and is given with an appropriate code sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, libgit2sharp is too slow on extracting blames and using this feature is impractical in real scenarios. So, the best way I think is to employ a  Powershell script to use the underlying superfast native git. And then redirect the result to your application.

```
git blame -l -e -c {commit-sha} -- "{file-path}" | where { $_ -match '(?<sha>\w{40})\s+\(<(?<email>[\w\.\-]+@[\w\-]+\.\w{2,3})>\s+(?<datetime>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d\:\d\d:\d\d\s-\d\d\d\d)\s+(?<lineNumber>\d+)\)\w*' } | 
foreach { new-object PSObject –prop @{  Email = $matches['email'];lineNumber = $matches['lineNumber'];dateTime = $matches['dateTime'];Sha = $matches['sha']}}
```